# Error C2059 : 'constant' when trying to create a Qt container in a header file with known size

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qvector

I am using Qt 4.8.5 with MSVC 2010 compiler and debugger from windows 7.0 SDK, and Qt creator as my IDE.

The following syntax works fine:

```
class Device
{
 public:
    Device();
    ....
    QVector<double> MyContainer;
    ....
 protected:
    ....
}
```

, where QContainer can be QVector, QList...etc, and T can be any type.

But the following syntax is denied by Qt creator and shows "Error C2059" while attempting to compile:

```
class Device
{
 public:
    Device();
    ....
    QVector<double> MyContainer(100);
    ....
 protected:
    ....
}
```

I am so confused since the document says the syntax "QContainer = MyContainer(szie)"is legitimate, but my Qt creator just can't read and it tells me there is an "unexpected token '('".

Am I doing worng?

Comment: What is `MyContainer`? And are you actually writing e.g. `QVector<SomeType> = MyContainer;`? Can you please show some more context (i.e. surrounding code)? And more specifically, please show us *real* code.

Comment: Sry I've added more information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are trying to assign to a *type*. `QVector<double>` is a type, and not a variable declaration or anything else you can assign to. That means that *both* examples are actually wrong.

I think you mean to declare the member variable `MyContainer`, for which you should use

```
QVector<double> MyContainer;
```

To initialize the container to a specific size, you have to use the constructors initializer list:

```
Device()
    : MyContainer(100)
{
    ...
}
```

For more information about initializer lists, see e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), or [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: I apologize that "=" is just a typo on my post, and I've corrected it . Besides, thank you very much, the links give me a lot of hints and clarifies my problem. Now I know how to fix this error, thank you!